# Contact form shows the success message but doesn't send email

Tags: javascript, email, sendmail, php

I have created the below php script for the contact page of my website. The problem with the script is that when a user fills and clicks the submit button, it show a success message but the email is not sent.
Can someone please check and tell me where I went wrong.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); // hide all basic notices from PHP

//If the form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

// require a name from user
if(trim($_POST['contactName']) === '') {
    $nameError =  'Forgot your name!'; 
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $name = trim($_POST['contactName']);
}

// need valid email
if(trim($_POST['email']) === '')  {
    $emailError = 'Forgot to enter in your e-mail address.';
    $hasError = true;
} else if (!preg_match("/^[[:alnum:]][a-z0-9_.-]*@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i", trim($_POST['email']))) {
    $emailError = 'You entered an invalid email address.';
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
}

// we need at least some content
if(trim($_POST['comments']) === '') {
    $commentError = 'You forgot to enter a message!';
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
        $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['comments']));
    } else {
        $comments = trim($_POST['comments']);
    }
}

// upon no failure errors let's email now!
if(!isset($hasError)) {

    $emailTo = 'info@example.com';
    $subject = 'Submitted message from '.$name;
    $sendCopy = trim($_POST['sendCopy']);
    $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nComments: $comments";
    $headers = 'From: ' .' <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);

    // set our boolean completion value to TRUE
    $emailSent = true;
}
}
?>

<!-- @begin contact -->
<div id="contact" class="section">
    <div class="container content">

        <?php if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent == true) { ?>
            <p class="info">Your email was sent. Sir!</p>
        <?php } else { ?>



            <div id="contact-form">
                <?php if(isset($hasError) || isset($captchaError) ) { ?>
                    <p class="alert">Error submitting the form</p>
                <?php } ?>

                <form id="contact-us" action="contacts.php" method="post">
            <div class="columns two contact_label alpha">
                Your Name 
            </div>
            <div class="columns five contact_input omega">
                <input type="text" name="contactName" id="contactName" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['contactName'])) echo $_POST['contactName'];?>" class="txt requiredField" placeholder="Name:" />
                        <?php if($nameError != '') { ?>
                            <br /><span class="error"><?php echo $nameError;?></span> 
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="clear"><!-- ClearFix --></div>
            <div class="columns two contact_label alpha">
                E-Mail Address
            </div>
            <div class="columns five contact_input omega">
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email']))  echo $_POST['email'];?>" class="txt requiredField email" placeholder="Email:" />
                        <?php if($emailError != '') { ?>
                            <br /><span class="error"><?php echo $emailError;?></span>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
            <div class="clear"><!-- ClearFix --></div>
                <div class="columns two contact_label alpha">
                Your Message
            </div>
            <div class="columns five contact_input omega">
                <textarea name="comments" id="commentsText" cols="45" rows="5" class="txtarea requiredField" placeholder="Message:"><?php if(isset($_POST['comments'])) { if(function_exists('stripslashes')) { echo stripslashes($_POST['comments']); } else { echo $_POST['comments']; } } ?></textarea>
                        <?php if($commentError != '') { ?>
                            <br /><span class="error"><?php echo $commentError;?></span> 
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
            <div class="clear"><!-- ClearFix --></div>

                <div class="columns five contact_button alpha omega offset-by-two">
                <input type="submit" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="Send Email" />
            </div>
            <div class="clear"><!-- ClearFix --></div> 


                </form>         

             </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div><!-- End #contact -->
```

Comment: Are you sure your server is configured to send mail? The couple good of answers you've gotten so far are telling you to check the actual status returned from `mail()` instead of just assuming it sent, if you make that change and it is still failing it could be because the server won't allow you to send mail.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion of where I should check in my server?

Comment: I'd start with the [sendmail stuff in your php.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php), in particular the `sendmail_path`, make sure it points to a valid install of sendmail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the line:

```
$emailSent = true;
```

And change the mail send line to

`$emailSent = mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);`

This sets $emailSent to true if the email is accepted for delivery. [PHP Mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: Thanks all of you. The code is still not work and my web host tells me that their server is ok. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);

    // set our boolean completion value to TRUE
    $emailSent = true;
```

do

`$emailSent = mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);`

otherwise you'll be hardcoding the result, why would you say that the email has been sent if you don't know? what are you, some kind of liar?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you should try to change the following:

```
if(!isset($hasError)) {
    ...
}
```

condition. You should type:

```
if(!$hasError)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your php mail smtp headers is properly configured. 
below are sample code which works for me. Copy and try it.

If the code below does not work for you then try to install Dropifi Contact Widget
(www.dropifi.com). They have a very intuitive contact form which you can customize to meet your need.

```
require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
require_once("class.smtp.php");

  class Email extends PHPMailer
  {       
      public function __construct(){
          parent::__construct(true);
          $this->IsSMTP();
          $this->SMTPAuth = true;
          $this->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
          $this->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
          $this->Port = 465;
          $this->Username = "someemail@gmail.com";
          $this->Password = "your password";
          $this->from = "no-reply@localhost.com";
          $this->FromName = "Webmaster";
          $this->WordWrap = 50;
          $this->IsHTML(true);
          $this->AddReplyTo("no-reply@localhost.com", "Webmaster");
          $this->Mailer = "smtp";
      }

      public function setReceiver($to){ 
          $this->AddAddress($to,"Administrator");
      }

      public function setSubject($subject){ 
          $this->Subject = $subject;
      }

      public function setMessage($param){

          $this->AltBody = "your alternative message";

          $message = "your main  message";
          $this->MsgHTML($message);
      }

      public function sendmail(){
          try{
              $flag = $this->Send();
              return $flag;
          }catch(phpmailerException $e){
              return $e->getMessage(); 
          }
      }
  }
```